# How to use SHOW TABLES with different tables in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of tables and I use

```
SHOW TABLES like 'my_table_%0';
```

But I need something like

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'my_table_%0' AND LIKE 'my_table_%1';
```

And it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try the below using OR

```
 SHOW TABLES
 FROM `<yourdbname>`
 WHERE 
`Tables_in_<yourdbname>` LIKE '%my_table_%0'
OR `Tables_in_<yourdbname>` LIKE '%my_table_%1';
```